# How to use realloc in a while loop so that it works for spaces of all sizes?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I am using malloc and realloc in a main function to create a string which increases by a byte whenever the user types in a character. However when the string reaches length = 15 it seems 
to stop allocating space and not read my error message? And eventually
After about 20 something characters it crashes. is it because I'm not freeing the data? Otherwise can someone tell me what is the problem?

```
int main()
{

  int loop = 1;
  int count = -1;
  int space_wanted;

  char * res;
  char * orig;
  char c;


  res = malloc(1);

  printf("Instructions: type q to quit. Continually type characters to add"
    " it to the string.\n");

  while (loop)
  {
    if ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
      if (c != 'q')
      {
        orig = res;

        /* One space for the new character and also for the
        null character */

        space_wanted = strlen(orig) + 2;

        char * new_space = realloc(res, space_wanted * 1.5);
        if (new_space == NULL)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "For some reason space was not able to be"
            " allocated.\n");
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        res = new_space;

        memcpy(res, orig, space_wanted);
        count++;
        res[count] = c;
        res[count + 1] = '\0';
      }
      else
      {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      }

    }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You are using `strlen` with a non-null-terminated string in `space_wanted = strlen(orig) + 2;` in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: `res = malloc(1);` -> `res = malloc(1); res[0] = 0;`

Comment: `realloc` can return the same memory pointer as passed to it, so you don't need to mess around with all that code copying strings.

Comment: @ChrisTurner the fact that `realloc` can return the same memory pointer is not relevant here. There is no need to copy, period. `realloc` does the copying.

Comment: I am not sure about this expression `space_wanted * 1.5`.  This can evaluate to a decimal number like 4.5 if `space_wanted` equals to 3.

Comment: @Nguaial realloc takes an int so any float calc will get rounded

Comment: @pm100 not rounded, but truncated (i.e. floored)

Comment: But `space_wanted * 1.5` is totally pointless, since you don't record the size of the current allocation. If you recorded the size, you could avoid the realloc if you already had enough space, but since you don't do that, you always do the realloc, so the extra space is never used.

Answer (score 0):

`realloc` will copy the old data to the new memory and free the old memory (if it needs to). This means that you don't need to (and shouldn't) copy from the old memory yourself:

```
orig = res;
char* new_space = realloc(res, space_wanted * 1.5);
res = new_space;
memcpy(res, orig, space_wanted); // <-- undefined behavior, orig is potentially freed
```

Answer (score 0):

Summing up all the inputs above, taking care of pesky newline character and make code more efficient, I came up with this code.

BTW, `count` should start at 0.

```
int main()
{

  int count = 0;
  int space_wanted;
  char * res;
  char c;


  res = malloc(1);
  *res = 0;   // or *res = '\0';

  printf("Instructions: type q to quit. Continually type characters to add"
     " it to the string.\n");

  while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != 'q' )
  {
     if ( c != '\n' )  //Disregard newline char
     {

        /* One space for the new character and also for the
           null character */

        space_wanted = strlen(res) + 2;

        if ( (res = realloc(res, space_wanted )) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "For some reason space was not able to be"
             " allocated.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        res[count++] = c;
        res[count] = '\0';

    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```